# writing a file in bash script

Tags: bash, unix

I a new to bash but I am trying to write a bash script which does the following:

```
write_to_file()
{
 #check if file exists
 # if not create the file
 # else open the file to edit
 # go in a while loop
 # ask input from user 
 # write to the end of the file
 # until user types  ":q"

 }
```

If anyone can point out the literature, I would be very thankful 
Thanks

Comment: Erm, literature would be `man bash`.

Comment: `man bash` is more of a reference manual, and a bit challenging for beginners. I think Fraz needs a tutorial. Try http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/.

Comment: Nice tutorial.  If you posted relevant links within that tutorial to address each item requested by Franz, that would be a great answer.

Comment: @RandallCook Please, no. To quote the `!abs` factoid in Freenode's `#bash` channel: The infamous "Advanced" Bash Scripting Guide should be avoided unless you know how to filter out the junk. It will teach you to write bugs, not scripts. In that light, the BashGuide was written: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Update: As it's a bash question, you should try this first. ;)

```
cat <<':q' >> test.file
```

To understand what is going on, read about bash's [IO redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html), [heredoc syntax](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html) and the [cat](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cat) command

---

As you see above, there are many ways to do it. To explain some more bash commands I've prepared the function also in the way you've requested it:

```
#!/bin/bash

write_to_file()
{

     # initialize a local var
     local file="test.file"

     # check if file exists. this is not required as echo >> would 
     # would create it any way. but for this example I've added it for you
     # -f checks if a file exists. The ! operator negates the result
     if [ ! -f "$file" ] ; then
         # if not create the file
         touch "$file"
     fi

     # "open the file to edit" ... not required. echo will do

     # go in a while loop
     while true ; do
        # ask input from user. read will store the 
        # line buffered user input in the var $user_input
        # line buffered means that read returns if the user
        # presses return
        read user_input

        # until user types  ":q" ... using the == operator
        if [ "$user_input" = ":q" ] ; then
            return # return from function
        fi

        # write to the end of the file. if the file 
        # not already exists it will be created
        echo "$user_input" >> "$file"
     done
 }

# execute it
write_to_file
```

Comment: @Fraz Was really fun! :) good question. I had just to follow your comments.

Comment: You don't need any of that stuff before the `while` loop.  `>>` already obeys the correct semantics.

Comment: `[ "$foo" == "bar" ]` isn't POSIX-compliant; POSIX sh only allows `=` inside of `[ ]`... and if you're _not_ going to try to be compatible with POSIX, you should be using `[[ ]]` (which is both more capable and less error-prone).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for your advices. Will read about this and maybe update the examples

Comment: @CarlNorum Yes, thats right. Read my update. I just wanted to show a test for the existence of a file works

Answer (score 6):

Example with basic argument checks:

```
write_to_file()
{
    while [ "$line" != ":q" ]; do
        read line
        if [ "$line" != ":q" ]; then
            printf "%s\n" "$line" >> "$1"
        fi  
    done
}

if [ "$#" -eq 1 ]; then
    write_to_file "$1"
else
    echo "Usage: $0 FILENAME"
    exit 2
fi
```

---

Or using the probably lesser known [until](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_03.html) construct, the function can be written a bit more terse:

```
# append to file ($1) user supplied lines until `:q` is entered
write_to_file()
{
    until read line && [ "$line" = ":q" ]; do
        printf "%s\n" "$line" >> "$1"
    done
}
```

Comment: Do not use `==` inside of `[` `]`; it is not POSIX-compatible (the compatible syntax is only a single `=`), and doesn't have the extra features and safety conferred by using the non-POSIX `[[ ]]` extension.

Comment: Also, `touch "$1"` and `write_to_file "$1"`; the quotes are necessary to avoid string-splitting and glob expansion.

Comment: Also, `echo $line >> $1` won't work right with a a line such as `-e foo` (the `-e` will be treated as an echo argument), and will collapse whitespace (`"foo   bar"` will be changed to `"foo bar"`).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, thanks for the critique; I hope I addressed all your hints.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Added an even terser version using [until](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_03.html). (miku ducks :)

Comment: @miku Call me nitpicky, but usage issues should send exit status of 2, not 1 (which is like a catchall).

Comment: @JohnStrood, thanks, wasn't away of /usr/include/sysexits.h (or http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html), but now I am :)

Answer (score 2):

This quick example should get you started:

```
while true
do
    read INPUT
    if [[ "${INPUT}" == :q ]]
    then
        return
    fi
    echo "${INPUT}" >> file
done
```

Comment: Not bad. One small enhancement might to be open `file` only once, when beginning the loop, instead of re-opening it every time one is ready to write another line.

Comment: Sure, you could also just concatenate the output into a variable and then write it once at the end.  I was going for minimum code & simplicity.

Comment: The bigger correctness error, by the way, is not quoting `${INPUT}` when passing it to echo. `printf '%s\n' "$INPUT"` would be ideal, but even `echo "$INPUT"` would be better; as it is, input of `*` would be replaced with a list of files, tabs and rows of multiple spaces next to each other get collapsed, etc.

Comment: Yes.  Safety first and all that.  Fixing.  Should do that for the test, too.

Comment: ...well, the test is safe; `[[ ]]` (unlike `[ ]`) implicitly prevents string-splitting or glob expansion.

Comment: O RLY?  What if the string were some other valid `[[` input?  I didn't try here.

Comment: `[[ ]]` is special syntax. Quotes are genuinely optional there. (If you have more questions on the subject, btw, feel free to pop in in freenode's #bash channel).

Answer (score 2):

There are several solutions here that are working *way* too hard.  Just do:

```
write_to_file() { sed '/^:q$/q' | sed '$d' >>"$1"; }
```

where the first argument is the name of the file.  That is, invoke it as:

```
write_to_file test.file
```